# Wrong plotmarkers in the legend generated by ListLinePlot

Tags: bugs, plotting

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 10.2 or earlier**

---

[`ListLinePlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLinePlot.html) generates the same legend for different lists of data when [`PlotMarkers`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotMarkers.html) and [`PlotStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotStyle.html) options are used:

```
list = {{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}}, {{2, 4}, {4, 6}, {6, 8}}};
ListLinePlot[list, PlotStyle -> Black, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 16}, 
PlotLegends -> {"A", "B"}]
```

[image]

Is this a bug?

I have *Mathematica v10.0.0* installed on *Windows 8 x64*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just have to specify the `LegendMarkers` accordingly:

```
list = {{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}}, {{2, 4}, {4, 6}, {6, 8}}};
ListLinePlot[list, PlotStyle -> Black, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 16},
 PlotLegends -> PointLegend[{"A", "B"}, LegendMarkers -> {Automatic, 16}]]
```

> [image: Plot]

Answer (score 3):

This bug was fixed in *Mathematica* v10.3 or earlier.

```
$Version
```

$\ $`"10.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (October 9, 2015)"`

```
list = {{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}}, {{2, 4}, {4, 6}, {6, 8}}};
ListLinePlot[list, PlotStyle -> Black, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 16},
  PlotLegends -> {"A", "B"}]
```

[image: fixedPlot]

Comment: I do observe this bug in version 10.0 on Windows but do not observe it in versions 10.2 and 9.0.1. So the bug is introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 10.2 or 10.1. I have changed the BUG header accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is that you define your own markers:

```
markers = {Graphics[{Black, Disk[]}], Graphics[{Black, Rectangle[]}]};

list = {{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}}, {{2, 4}, {4, 6}, {6, 8}}};

ListPlot[list,
 PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[{"A", "B"},
   LegendMarkers -> markers,
   LegendLabel -> "Series",
   LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, RoundingRadius -> 5] &),
   LegendMargins -> 5],
 Joined -> True,
 PlotStyle -> Black,
 PlotMarkers -> Table[{size, 0.05}, {size, markers}]]
```

[image]